# Слово "прелюбодеяние"

Tags: этимология

Прелюбодеяние - измена, разврат. А вот интересно было бы понять происхождение этого слова (конечно, не будем брать трактовку Задорнова))).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне хотелось бы уточнить значение приставки ПРЕ.

Во всех источниках и форумных разговорах на эту тему обычно называется или значение ПРЕВОСХОДНОЙ СТЕПЕНИ ("слишком любимое, отчего стало губительным - потребляет все силы, в ущерб другим делам, которые нужны для всестороннего развития Человека"), или значение "ПЕРЕСТУПАНИЯ" через закон.

Но попробуем сравнить: не любодействуй - не прелюбодействуй, смысл практически одинаков. Так что же дает нам приставка ПРЕ?

Для ответа на этот вопрос рассмотрим слова "пребывать, претерпеть, преходящий". Здесь ПРЕ имеет значение перехода через временное состояние (пребывать - это быть, находиться где-то в течение некоторого времени).

Возможно, что "прелюбодействовать" -  это также "любодействовать" в определенный временной промежуток, пребывать в состояние прелюбодеяния. Тогда приставка ПРЕ не имеет отношения ни к превосходной степени, ни к преступлению в значении "переступить закон".

Answer (score 1):

Прелюбоде́яние - от глагола прелюбоде́ять., прелюбоде́йствовать. Заимств. из цслав., ср. ст.-слав. прѣлюбы дѣѩти, любы дѣѩти μοιχεύειν с древней формой вин. ед. прѣлюбы, любы (см. любо́вь); см. Соболевский,форма любО- (уже в сербск.-цслав., русск.-цслав. любодѣи μοιχός) получила -О- по аналогии от др. сложений.

Ильинский (Некот. архаизмы) объясняет ст.-слав. любы дѣѩти как вин. мн. от формы любъ, против этого Соболевский, там же.

ПРЕ- приставка, которая придает словам значение предельной 
степени действия, превосходящего какую-либо меру, норму или высшей степени качества;+ любы-любовь во мн.ч. + деяния .

Историч. словарь говорит: (http://enc-dic.com/history/Preljubodejanie-32900.html) Прелюбодеяние-незаконная связь и преступное действие под влиянием любовного влечения, первое из дел плоти (Гал 5.19, ср. Мк 10.19). Поэтому уклонение от Бога и пристрастие к идолам Писание также называет прелюбодеянием (Иез 23.37). (См. блуд) Как видим, слово в Писании использовалось не только в значении любовной связи:

•«Прелюбодеяние» иногда использовалось в отношении идолопоклонства (Иеремии 3:8  ). Стих 9   говорит, что Израиль совершил прелюбодейные действия с камнями и деревьями.Но не всегда.
•   «Прелюбодеяние» иногда использовалось в отношении исканий чудес (От Матфея 12:39  ).Но не всегда.
•«Прелюбодеяние» иногда использовалось в отношении зла вообще (Иакова 4:4  , Осии 7:1-4  ). Но не всегда.

Где бы ни встречалось это слово, ему всегда присуще значение неверности, измены, нарушения обязанностей, скреплённых договором. Прежде чем в английском языке появилось слово adultery (прелюбодеяние) Джон Виклифф и Вильям Тиндейл сделали свои переводы Нового Завета. В отрывке «о разводе», таком как Матфея 19:9   они одинаково перевели это слово «breaketh wedlock» (разрушает брак). 
http://khristos.org/article/197

Глагольная форма «adulterate» («изменять») означает «делать нечистым, фальсифицированным или худшим, посредством подмешивания чуждых или несоответствующих составляющих»,а в форме существительного это слово переосмыслилось и имеет совершенно другое значение -измена в браке, причём этимология этого слова не приводится ни в английском словаре, ни в греческом, ни в еврейском. Почему? Потому что это слово определяется произвольно, в полном пренебрежении его происхождением, его основной формой и его использованием в Библии.Собственно, как и слово "крестить кого-то"(обряд крещения)произвольно связывается со словом "крест".

Answer (score 1):

Прелюбодеяние  -  то  же,  что  и  любодеяние,  но  в  превосходной  степени.  И  то  и  другое  -  дело  нехорошее,  потому,  что  для  любви,  как  дела  хорошего,  есть  другие  слова  и  другие  словосочетания.  Хотя  корень  во  всех  случаях  в  русском  языке  один.  Но  ведь  и  многозначимость   никто  ещё  не  отменял.  Да  и  не  только  в  русском   слово   слово  любовь  используют   в  значении  слова  секс  (  это  слово  у  нас  довольно  молодое  ),  французы   тоже  любовь  "делают".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что приставку "пре" здесь правомернее рассматривать со словом "ПРЕступление". То есть как переход какой-то черты, закона. Что же за закон нарушается в данном случае? Вернёмся к слову "любодеяние". На мой взгляд, в нём нет ничего греховного, ошибочного. Напротив, всё нами делаемое должно делаться с любовью (а, как общеизвестно, Бог и есть любовь). Значит, преступление здесь видится в игнорировании допустимых пределов любви, желания и не соответствия ожиданий в результате такого любодеяния, что вызывает разочарование, депрессию, уныние и всё, что с этим связано. Таким образом, преступление совершается против гармонии триединства - желание-осознание-поступок. Эти три вектора (прямоугольная система координат) дают в сложении тот единственно истинный вектор, который и определяет степень ошибочности(греховности) всей нашей жизни. Резюмируя, можно сказать, что прелюбодеяние - не что иное, как избыточность чувств над осознанностью и, как результат, конечной неудовлетворённостью совершённого действия, а само слово "любодеяние" носит негативный смысл, так как в него не входит осознанность.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то в одном чате родилось такое значение (на поиски которого в дискуссиях, размышлениях ушло пол года, почему это плохо):
"Те, кто мне сейчас стали слать порно ролики вместо здрасьте, типа "давайте потрахаемся", вы ошиблись.
Любви в этом нет, ни в какой форме. Вот и нашли, что есть прелюбодеяние )
Пред любовью* деяние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почувствовала, что по идее.. останавливать должна и не заповедь.

Сама девушка, если она не развращена последними веяниями вседозволенной моды (если она живëт не по моде, а по природе) не под опьянением и пр. не позволит мужчине вторгнуться в своë пространство столь бесцеремонно.

Такова природа: чувственное начало женщины и плотское мужчины, закручивают вихрь  разнополярных эмоций!

Отсутствие полярности ☯ и есть, получается, разврат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]